# I want to display all items within an ID that is hovered in list view

Tags: sql, vb.net, listview, contextmenustrip

I have list view wherein New orders from customers is display. Items shown are Order ID, Order Date, and total price of customer's order. here is what it looks like.

[Click this to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DcFM.png)

How can I display all items within hovered Order ID? I want to display them as something like a list, maybe looks like drop down list.

the idea is something like this.
[Whenever I hover the Order ID, I want the Items in hovered Order to be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwxK9.png)

Any help is appreciated. Thank you guys!

Comment: Here's a tutorial: http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/Tutorials/Controls/ToolTip.html

Comment: based on what I see. The possible way to do this is using context menu strip and list view, but i cant see anything that could help me

Comment: Ah, just seen your edit. The only way I know to achieve that effect is to create your own custom forms. Then use the mouse hover events in the listview to show it.

Comment: Yeah, a custom form with a `ListView` or the like could do the job. You'd want to make sure that the form didn't steal focus when it was shown.  The `UnselectableForm` class provided here can do that. http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?459890-Building-Blocks-for-an-On-screen-Keyboard